# Cordova plugin development in C# for Windows 8.1 / Windows 10

Tags: c#, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-win10

Is it possible to write a Cordova plugin for Windows (8.1/10) in C#?  Alternatively, can a library component written in C# be wrapped as a Cordova plugin?  If I haven't missed anything, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903769.aspx) and [Apache](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_platforms_win8_plugin.md.html#Windows%20Plugins) documentation only show how to use C# for Windows Phone 8 (a JS implementation is expected for "Windows Universal")

Comment: This guide explains how to create a plugin for both Windows Phone 8 and Windows Universal: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-plugin-windows-phone/

Answer (score 2):

Yes but there are some requirements. First, your library must be a Windows Runtime Component project. You can reference a winmd or a csproj in your plugin (see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/latest/guide/platforms/win8/plugin.html). If your plugin is valid and correctly loaded in your application at runtime, you can use your C# classes in JavaScript directly (it's just WinJS). It's your responsability to expose a JavaScript wrapper of your C# library in the plugin, but it's not mandatory (just common to maximize code sharing with other platforms implementations of your plugin).

Comment: Did you try to build such project in release mode? I'm currently having troubles while creating app packages, because as I understand I need to use .net native and it doesn't produce good results. It simply doesn't pack required .dlls into the .appx.

Comment: Yes, I just need to create package one by one for each specific architecture (x86, x64, ARM) because my Windows Runtime Component was wrote in C++ : bundles was not working for my project. Any CPU mode is not an option in your case if you want .NET native. But, for a standard C# Cordova plugin, .NET native is not required and you can build just one package (with Any CPU mode)

Comment: If I build without .NET native compilation then the Store complains about unsupported APIs, for example "API OpenSemaphore in api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. System.Threading.dll calls this API". It's a strange thing, I'm not sure if this use case is even covered by the store submission process. Nevertheless, I worked around this issue by implementing everything in JS and not dealing with Windows Runtime Component, .NET native and .dlls.