# How to create Apache Cordova plugin for Windows 8.1 with C#?

Tags: c#, cordova, plugins, windows-8.1, apache-cordova

How an Apache Cordova plugin can be created for Windows 8.1?

I've searched all the web and all I could find is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34285819/2471497) which is too general. Does anybody have a step by step guide on how to create the plugin with C#? How Windows Runtime Component should be created in C# and how exactly should it be referenced by JavaScript plugin wrapper in Cordova?

Unfortunately, [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/win8/plugin.html) only part of the solution is described.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Globalization plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization) - it's a Cordova core plugin with Windows part written in C# (with JS proxy calling WinRT component, which is a standard way).

BTW I have not found any step-by-step tutorial exactly answering the question.