# Using C# native code for windows Universal cordova custom plugin

Tags: c#, cordova, win-universal-app, cordova-plugins, onsen-ui

I am building a cordova custom plugin to interact with a laser barcode scanner on an Honeywell device, to utilize in my hybrid Cordova + Onsen app. 
I have been reading documentation for days but it looks like that a big issue is to include some C# code (which is the only way I have to interact with the Laser scanner) into the custom plugin. As far I could understand, ( and this is also backed up from the microsoft and cordova documentation) starting from windows phone 8.1 native code for custom plugin will be written with Javascript, while windows phone 8 will still use C# as native language.
So the question is, is there a way to still write a plugin for windows universal apps (meaning from WP 8.1 +) that include some native C# code?

I am using this code in the plugin.xml (this is just the platform part, which I think is wrong because of the .cs file instead of the .js file)

```
    <platform name="windows">

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="sayHelloPlugin">
    <param name="wp-package" value="sayHelloPlugin" />
</feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/wp8/sayHello.cs" />
</platform>
```

But I receive the error "**Missing command error**" when I try to call the plugin from my app.
It is for me more important to make it work, so if you have any suggestion for possible workaround it would still be a huge help.

Please don´t hesitate to ask for more info or code.

There was also a question in the past on this regard, but the answer telling that "Yes, it is possible" it´s not that helpful :P 
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598250/cordova-plugin-development-in-c-sharp-for-windows-8-1-windows-10)

Comment: Cordova plugin for Windows Phone 8.1 accepts only .winmd and .dll files. See [Defining your plugin in plugin.xml](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/plugin.html#defining-your-plugin-in-pluginxml);

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I ve started working on it using the Windows Runtime component project template in Visual Studio 15. But still, not an easy task. Do you have any reference or maybe sample code how does Runtime Components works and especially how can I call them / integrate them in my Cordova App?